# Change CSS if table width exceeds page

Tags: css, responsive-design, css-tables

With responsive CSS, it is possible to execute certain CSS based on the screen size. For example:

```
@media all and max-width: 1024px {...}
```

to set CSS only for screens with a width smaller than 1024. Now my goal is to execute CSS when the width of an element (in my case, a table) exceeds the page width.

So simply said, I want CSS to be executed when my table wouldn't fit on my page.

If this is not possible, it is also ok to compare the width of my table with a fixed value. So css which will be added when a certain element has a width larger than ... px.

The reason why I want to do this is that I don't want a table to exceed the page width. The table can have a different amount of columns, based on the output of a PHP script.

I know this can be done with Javascript, but I am looking for a CSS solution.

Comment: You can use media-queries to hide some not so important columns to fit table, but it will not guarantee 100% fit. Also, consider `overflow-x: auto` on wrapper to allow scrolling horizontally when it does not fits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a straightforward way to do what you want with pure CSS, but there's a good rundown of creative approaches to this problem at
http://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-table-roundup/

**Edit:
To be more specific, perhaps the easiest to apply to your situation would be ZURB's responsive tables technique, which requires simply linking the files reponsive-tables.js and responsive-tables.css to your HTML document, then adding the appropriate class name to your `table` element.
You can read more about it and download the files at http://zurb.com/playground/responsive-tables.

Comment: Good call, Mister Dood. Edited answer to discuss a specific technique.